# Property Address->alias is empty in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

Some users are getting the error

> (Property Address->alias is empty at line 909 in file classes/ObjectModel.php)

while checking out, but other users can check out successfully.

What is failing?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Please include the content of the screenshot. That makes your question easier to read and helps StackOverflow find related questions. If a screenshot is the best way to show information, post it as an image, not a link.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Thanks for replay, now check screenshot i hope you understand

Comment: Those users have the field alias empty for the address. When validating the data, it will give that error. Usually that field is saved with "My address" by default, but something must be preventing that. You could add that information to every address to prevent this, or inform the users.

Comment: @sadlyblue thanks, can you please guide me from where i add that address information to prevent this for every user

Comment: @sadlyblue User have already added address but still getting error i don't understand why getting error.

Comment: check if that address has the field alias empty or not.

Comment: I checked alias of address is empty in database and i add the value in alias but now i get another error "Property Address->address1  is empty"